# Modal window on vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Started learning vue js. I can not create a modal window. What is my problem? How to link a button element that is in the Header.vue component and a modal window in Modal.vue?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-z78ev)

Comment: You need to first import the modal component into the header component, or have them both imported in the app component. Then you can do a @click on a button in the header to access the modal

Comment: @NateBeers [Didn't I already call both components in App.vue?](https://i.gyazo.com/ccb130c441c31f8222aceb6a56a8df43.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited [your code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-3xqq6), to make it work. However, you'll need to create a "close" button in the modal itself, to toggle `isModalLoginVisible` back to `false`. You can pass the same click handler to the `Modal.vue` to make the close button work.

Both of your components should be called in a common component, such as `App.vue`. Create a click handler in the `App.vue` component and pass the handler as a prop to the `Header.vue` component. In the `Header.vue` component, pass the click handler to the button `@click` property. The click handler, in the `App.vue` component, will toggle a flag which will decide whether the `Modal.vue` component should be visible or not, using the `v-if` directive.

Comment: [Didn't I already call both components in App.vue?](https://i.gyazo.com/ccb130c441c31f8222aceb6a56a8df43.png)

Comment: Instead of two methods, show and close, create only one to toggle. It will make the flag false, if true and vice-versa. Pass the toggle method to Header as prop. And in Header use it in @click for button. I will try to give you the exact code in some time, if this doesn't help.

Comment: I try, but it doesn’t work out, maybe you can help me by writing the code if it doesn’t complicate you.

Comment: I have edited the answer and included the edits to your code; hope it'll help. By studying the edits I made to your code, you'll be able to pass the click handler to `Modal.vue` without any problem.